# td appear below other td in html table

Tags: html

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a table row in HTML 2 rows high so that I have.

```
---------------------
|<td></td>|<td></td>|      <- all within one <tr></tr> block
|-------------------|
|<td>          </td>|
---------------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your drawing, i think you want the following:

```
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Note that this is done in two rows, not one.

If you really wan't it to be that way, Divs are the way to go...

```
<div id="container" style="width:501px">
    <div id="column1" style="width:49%; float:left; border:1px solid #000"> Some content here </div>
    <div id="column2" style="width:49%; float:left; border:1px solid #000"> Some content here </div>
    <br style="height:0px; clear:both"/>
    <div id="column3" style="width:98%; border:1px solid #000"> Some content here </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The numbers are slightly off but for the sake of speed, I didn't make things line up exactly

Comment: I thought the same thing but he wants it in the same table row.

Comment: I would like it in the same row.

Comment: Added an edit. I don't know of a way to get a table row to span 2 rows in the way you want it to, but it can be done with some CSS magic using DIVs. Note that you will need to spend some time to get the numbers right (not use percents, use padding, margins, etc) to make it look the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<td colspan="2">Will take two cells' width</td>`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a new row to do that.

If you use an unordered list, you can use floats to obtain the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the following:

```
<table width="500px">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="500px">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just change `500px` for the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

He wants to enclose everything in 1 TR.
A possible solution is to enclose another table within that TD.

```
<tr> 
<td>
<table style="width:100%;margin:0">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```